# Mouse simulation with SendInput

Tags: c#, mouse, simulation, sendinput

I made some application for automatic processing.
It used SendInput in C#
I tested that code on my PC, it's working fine.
But now I installed that app on other PC, but it's not working.
I attached some code snippet for understanding.

```
    public static void ClickLeftMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
    public static void ClickRightMouseButton()
    {
        INPUT mouseDownInput = new INPUT();
        mouseDownInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseDownInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseDownInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));

        INPUT mouseUpInput = new INPUT();
        mouseUpInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;
        mouseUpInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP;
        SendInput(1, ref mouseUpInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }

    public static void SetMousePosition(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        INPUT mouseMoveInput = new INPUT();
        mouseMoveInput.type = SendInputEventType.InputMouse;

        mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dwFlags = MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MouseEventFlags.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;

        mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dx = 65535 * x / width;
        mouseMoveInput.mkhi.mi.dy = 65535 * y / height;

        SendInput(1, ref mouseMoveInput, Marshal.SizeOf(new INPUT()));
    }
```

As you can see from code snippet, I called 2 functions.

```
    MouseSimulator.SetMousePosition(Convert.ToInt16(mAction.x_pos), Convert.ToInt16(mAction.y_pos), 1920, 1080);
    MouseSimulator.ClickLeftMouseButton();
```

But on the other PC, it's not working.
I only can access to that PC via Chrome RDP or TeamViewer.
I published my application and installed that package on that PC.
But SendInput not working.
What shall I do?
Windows OS of 2 PCs(mine and other) are all Win10.

Comment: is the user you are using to that installed application has an Admin rights? Try to check. or you r application also if it has an Admin rights.

Comment: The user that installed application is Administrator.
And both computers are all Win10 64bit.

Comment: But now, how can I check my application has an admin rights ?

Comment: Thanks, Vijunav.
I uploaded debug compiled files, and run that with administrative permit, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

In order to execute SendInput, need to have admin rights.